# SQL Query to update earliest date for unique combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the Contract_Start date to be the earliest date for each unique Company and Route combination.  For example, the Contract_Start for the first three records should be 1/15/12 as Company = 1 and Route = 1 for all three.  The Contract_Start would then change to 1/20/12 for record 4 as that is the earliest date for the combination of Company = 1 and Route = 2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Company   Route   Driver   Date      Contract_Start
1         1       A        1/29/12
1         1       B        2/3/12
1         1       C        1/15/12
1         2       A        1/28/12
1         2       B        1/20/12
2         1       A        1/7/12
2         1       B        1/16/12
2         2       A        2/9/12
1         2       B        1/4/12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query with subquery can solve your problem

```
UPDATE TABLE TABLE T 
SET CONTRACT_START = (
   SELECT MIN(DATE) 
   FROM TABLE TI
   WHERE T.COMPANY = TI.COMPANY 
     AND T.ROUTE = TI.ROUTE
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked as expected, although I had to add another From at the end to make the alias T for the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function to get Contract_Start. You needn't to store it at the table.

```
select Company, Route, Driver, Date, min(Date) over(partition by Company, Route) as Contract_Start
from myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE with  window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, min(date) over (partition by company, route) as min_date
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set contract_start = min_date;
```

Updatable CTE/subqueries/views are a very handy feature in SQL Server and quite powerful when combined with window functions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this approach will resolve your issue and fulfill your task requirements.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET Contract_Start = CE.Date1 
     FROM Table_Name TB JOIN (
        SELECT Company,Route,date1, Count(*) AS Countnum, 
        Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Company, Route ORDER BY date1 ASC) AS Rownumber 
        FROM Table_Name GROUP BY Company,Route,date1) as CE ON TB.Company = CE.Company AND TB.Route = CE.Route
WHERE Rownumber = 1;
```